# How to use DSL metaprogramming with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, metaprogramming

I'm trying to work on a DSL to manage different locales within the same route, like `get "/test"`. The

This is an exercise to learn how to extend Sinatra, therefore `Rack::Locale` or a similar tool is not a valid answer.

Based on the body of the request JSON body, assuming I receive JSON as POST or PUT, I want to respond with the specific locale.

I currently have a barebones script, of what I think I need:

```
class Locale
  attr_reader :locale_id
  attr_reader :described_class

  alias :current_locale :locale_id

  def initialize(locale_id, &block)
    @locale_id = locale_id
    instance_eval &block
  end

end

def locale(locale_id, &block)
  Locale.new(locale_id, &block)
end
```

I am missing the capability to respond based on the locale in the `request.body` JSON I receive as input, and  the class here has something else I do not yet see that is needed or is missing.

An example of how this would get used would be:

```rb
get '/' do 
   locale 'cs-CS' do 
     "Czech"
     #or db query or string
   end 
   locale 'en-UK' do 
     "British english"
     #or db query or string
   end
end
```

Therefore to try to clarify even more clearly I will try with a TDD approach:

As User when I send a JSON that contains: `"locale": "cs-CS"` the result is Czech.

Comment: Can you show your attempt to use it from a route handler?

Comment: sure thing!
`get '/' do
  locale 'cs-CS' do
    "Czech"
  end
  locale 'en-UK' do
    "British english"
  end
end`

Sorry but I cannot format it correctly here in the comments.

Comment: Don't use comments to add code or input data or required results. Comments are for questions and queries asking to clarify something. Edit your question and put the information into it where it would have been if you'd included it initially. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags to mark the change, just add it so the question makes sense. We can see when and where things changed if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for helping me sorting this out in the proper way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [Extending The DSL](http://sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-dsl-class-context-with-sinatraregister) and the Conditions section of the [README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html)?

Right now, you're not really extending the DSL. I'd redesign it slightly, because it looks like you'd want to match on a case statement but that would mean creating lots of classes or an ugly matching statement. But, Sinatra already has some really nice ways to match on routes and conditions. So, something like this would be more idiomatic:

```
post '/', :locale => "Czech" do
  "Czech"
end

post '/', :locale => "British English" do
  "British"
end
```

or

```
post '/', :locale => "en-GB" do
  "cs-CS"
end

post '/', :locale => "cs-CS" do
  "cs-CS"
end
```

How to do this? First, you'll need a filter to transform the JSON coming in:

```
before do
  if request.media_type == "application/json"
    request.body.rewind
    @json = JSON.parse request.body.read
    @locale = @json["locale"] && Locales[@json["locale"]]
  end
end
```

and then you'll need a condition to check against:

```
set(:locale) {|value|
  condition {
    !!@locale && (@locale == value || @json["locale"] == value)
  }
}
```

All together (app.rb):

```
require 'sinatra'

Locales = {
  'cs-CS' => "Czech",
  'en-GB' => "British English"
}

before do
  if request.media_type == "application/json"
    request.body.rewind
    @json = JSON.parse request.body.read
    @locale = @json["locale"] && Locales[@json["locale"]]
  end
end


set(:locale) {|value|
  condition {
    !!@locale && (@locale == value || @json["locale"] == value)
  }
}


post '/', :locale => "en-GB" do
  "cs-CS"
end


post '/', :locale => "cs-CS" do
  "cs-CS"
end
```

That works but it won't work as an extension. So, relying the docs I posted at the top:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module Localiser

    Locales = {
      'cs-CS' => "Czech",
      'en-GB' => "British English"
    }

    def localise!(locales=Locales)
      before do
        if request.media_type == "application/json"
          request.body.rewind
          @json = JSON.parse request.body.read
          @locale = @json["locale"] && locales[@json["locale"]]
        end
      end

      set(:locale) {|value|
        condition {
          !!@locale && (@locale == value || @json["locale"] == value)
        }
      }
    end
  end
  register Localiser
end
```

Now it will extend the DSL. For example:

```
require "sinatra/localiser"
class Localised < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Localiser

  localise!


  post '/', :locale => "Czech" do
    "Czech"
  end


  post '/', :locale => "British English" do
    "British"
  end


  ["get","post"].each{|verb|
    send verb, "/*" do
      "ELSE"
    end
  }

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Hopefully that helps clarify a few things for you.

Comment: Wow @iain,  thanks a lot! Is not exactly answering my needs but from a general prospective, is a great way to start. The thing is that the behavior I am trying to apply with the locale is within Sinatra, but is to extend another DSL I am looking at. I will update my question to clarify even further, but your answer is amazingly detailed and analytic.

Comment: @M.Litalek Thanks, I thought you posted an interesting question. I'll keep an eye on the question for edits and if I think of anything else useful I'll update this. Regardless, I hope you find a good solution.